# Binance spot and funding wallet addresses - where to find?

Tags: binance

Is there a way to see the addresses for these wallets? Customer service weren't very helpful with this.

Answer (score 0):

Some custodial wallets don't have addresses because they are just wallets in name only and are really accounts. The account holder has no money so far as the Bitcoin network is concerned.

When you spend or withdraw Bitcoin using this kind of "wallet", you are really issuing a request to the custodian to send money from their wallet. The sending address belongs to the custodian not you.